# how to convert kilobytes to megabytes in javascript

Tags: javascript

how to convert 4000 kilobytes to 4 megabytes in javascript?

i have tried

```
function formatSizeUnits(bytes){
      if      (bytes>=1073741824) {bytes=(bytes/1073741824).toFixed(2)+' GB';}
      else if (bytes>=1048576)    {bytes=(bytes/1048576).toFixed(2)+' MB';}
      else if (bytes>=1024)       {bytes=(bytes/1024).toFixed(2)+' KB';}
      else if (bytes>1)           {bytes=bytes+' bytes';}
      else if (bytes==1)          {bytes=bytes+' byte';}
      else                        {bytes='0 byte';}
      return bytes;
}


formatSizeUnits(4000);
```

Ans I get is  "3.91 KB". i need to get 4mb

Comment: Use `Math.round(bytes/1024)+' KB';`

Comment: 4000 kilobytes is usually not considered equal to 4MB - though there are exceptions where this applies. If you want your function to be such an exception, replace the divisors with 1000000000, 1000000 and 1000 respectively

Comment: probably you meant `4kb` instead of `4mb`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function is correct. It accepts bytes only. But what your trying to do is `formatSizeUnits(4000)`. this is wrong and the expected output is `3.91 MB` as it is divided by 1024 and not with 1000. The correct ways is to call like

```
 formatSizeUnits(4000*1024)  // beacuse 4000 is in KB and convert into bytes
```

See the below snippet to get the correct answer

```js
function formatSizeUnits(bytes){
      if      (bytes>=1073741824) {bytes=(bytes/1073741824).toFixed(2)+' GB';}
      else if (bytes>=1048576)    {bytes=(bytes/1048576).toFixed(2)+' MB';}
      else if (bytes>=1024)       {bytes=(bytes/1024).toFixed(2)+' KB';}
      else if (bytes>1)           {bytes=bytes+' bytes';}
      else if (bytes==1)          {bytes=bytes+' byte';}
      else                        {bytes='0 byte';}
      return bytes;
}


document.write(formatSizeUnits(4000*1024));
```